# Basic09 to Windows7

Tags: basic

I want to open a Basic 09 code under windows 7.
I just want to read the code. I do not want to execute it.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: From an old CoCo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Not a definite answer, just some information about the issues at work)*

Might not be as easy as it seems.

For one, [BASIC09](https://colorcomputerarchive.com/repo/Documents/Manuals/Programming/BASIC09%20Programming%20Language%20Reference%20Manual%20-%20Revision%20H%20(Microware%20System%20Corp).pdf) is, unlike most other BASICs a compiler, generating I-Code. In today's lingo one might call that a Bytecode. The code generated does not include all source information. For example procedure or variable names were replaced by their target address, not only speeding up execution but saving space as well. On the down side this means when 'disassembling' the code, not all information can be regained. ([This Answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14901/6659) got some additional information)

Next, BASIC09 contained an optimizer, removing dead code, evaluating constant expressions, reorganizing expressions and alike. So while the compiler itself would just make names harder to read (for most parts), the packer will change code further away from the source it was created from.

Lastly a packed program could be linked into a stand alone version carrying a minimized BASIC runtime, further complicated the way to create source code again.

All of that was as well version dependent.

---

P.S.: Sure about using Windows 7?

Comment: You can of course `LIST*` to a file, which gives you the program's source code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have to dig out my coco in the seller Somewhere.
I also notice that there is a [java Emulator](https://laptrinhx.com/6809-and-os-9-emulator-in-java-616009523/).

I will install it on ubuntu. I included the link.

Comment: Both [VCC](https://github.com/VCCE/VCC) and [XRoar](https://www.6809.org.uk/xroar/) emulators run under Windows, and there are instructions for running [NitrOS-9](https://nitros9.sourceforge.io/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) on both